# SSH Keys Broken

Tags: homebrew, ssh

I had keys set up for SSH'ing to a remote server without password, however they no longer work. The only change I can think of is that I install HomeBrew - I did not update / install a new OpenSSH.

My approach for keys:

```
% ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Copy id_rsa.pub to remote server and append to

```
~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

But now I am being asked for passwords each time I login. Is this related to HomeBrew? My friend is able to access the same server using the same approach on the same model of MacBook Pro, prior to installing HomeBrew.

Edit:

```
% ssh -vvv host
...
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/jamieborder/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:1WyWpE6/LdZHP5lbhWF9I8rF4NUBhopfTm9nJ/2Iros explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: entering
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
...
```

Comment: I can’t see how installing Homebrew would break SSH.  Have you tried connecting anf manually specifying the identity fike?

Comment: I thought it might've changed permissions or something. What do you mean manually sorry? I've added 'Host xx\nIdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa' to my ~/.ssh/config

Comment: What does `ssh -vvv host` say the problem is?

Comment: Added what I think is relevant section of output to edit, thanks

Comment: And also tried `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa host' with same result.

Comment: Can you get your friend to check the sshd logs on the server you're connecting to? Somewhere in /var/log/ typically auth.log That should tell you why the server rejected the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the logs you shared, you may want to check why this is present:

```
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
```

It seems this error log isn't very specific from client side logging, to have more information, you might want to enable server side logging, also check some potential root cause

## Enable server side logging

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875126/we-did-not-send-a-packet-disable-method) from [TripeHound](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2096401/tripehound) where he explains how to run a local `sshd` server, which allows you to see both client and server side logs:

> Start a new SSH Server instance on a new port in debug mode with:
>
> ```
> /usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 2222
> ```
>
> then connect to it from the client with:
>
> ```
> ssh -p 2222 user@host
> ```

You can then check authentication failures using (more info [here](https://serverfault.com/a/480433/1003635)):

```
grep 'sshd' /var/log/auth.log
```

## Troubleshooting options

Hopefully server side logs will help, in any case here are some possible root causes for that error that were shared on [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131886/73128)

- [Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875126/we-did-not-send-a-packet-disable-method) Login shell for the account is set incorrectly in `/etc/passwd`

Make sure shell used to login has been changed by somebody else, if you use a shared user to connect for example, maybe check with your friend as he can access the server

- [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66805502) Bad permissions on the home directory, ssh keys, config folder

```
chmod g-w /home/user
chmod 700 /home/user/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

- [Post 3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131886/ssh-public-key-wont-send-to-server) A malformed authorized_keys file on the destination host

Hope this helps, don't hesitate to provide more information if it doesn't (like server-side logs)

Comment: You need to summarise the information provided in the links, and provide enough detail that others can confirm the answer is correct. Just posting links isn't helpful, as if they disappear, then your answer is meaningless. An answer should be self-contained where possible.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful feedback, I didn't think about that, it makes sens indeed ! Updated, don't hesitate if you spot more improvements

Comment: Thanks for the very in-depth response. The issue was the permissions of my home directory on the remote server (related to post 2), which was not something I thought I was able to change.